# How to let phpMyAdmin connect online server?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I’m running a server locally I have that all setup and running good, but when I try to connect to my phpMyAdmin server it gives me this error

> Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it. in C:\server\htdocs\comment.php on
>   line 3

Here are my connection settings:

```
mysql_connect("76.4.50.73","root","");
mysql_select_db("comments");
```

I have also tried `127.0.0.1` but since its not on my `localhost` it does not work

Comment: Have you tried contacting whoever hosts your phpmyadmin server?

Comment: Are you sure that the port is open for MySQL?

Comment: yea its running through port 3306 a normal port. I was thinking that it had something to do with my fire wall but phpmyadmin doesn't work with .exe files to let it through it might be a config file but im trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

MySQL ports—and virtually any DB port—is not open to the outside world. So the chances of you connecting remotely via `root` are slim to none. Especially `root`. Running an `nmap` scan of port `3306` on the IP address you are providing shows it as `filtered`:

```
$ nmap 76.4.50.73 -p3360

Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-03 21:51 EDT
Nmap scan report for tx-76-4-50-73.dhcp.embarqhsd.net (76.4.50.73)
Host is up (0.37s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3360/tcp filtered unknown
```

For all intents and purposes `filtered` means the port is blocked by something & just cannot be accessed.

I would recommend contacting your ISP to see if they can open up port `3306` for you. Chances are they will give you a non-`root` login & then even ask you to use SSH tunneling to connect.